# Feeding a function output back to it as input parameter

Tags: python

I am writing a simple function and I want to iteratively run it so that it gets fed its own output, performs some operations and continues to do so until a certain number of times.

I have tried the following:

```
def optimize(lst):
    A = lst[0]
    B = lst[1]
    C = lst[2]
    # perform some operation, for example,
    A = A+1
    B = B+1
    C = C+1
    new_lst = [A,B,C]
    lst[:] = new_lst # this overwrites the original param with the new output
    print(new_lst)
    return(new_lst)

for i in range(3):
    optimize([1,2,3])
```

This just repeats for three times with the same input, i.e., 1,2,3 and prints [2,3,4]. It's not getting updated in each iteration. I mean it should take [2,3,4] and spit out [3,4,5] and so on.
I know I am missing a very simple concept here. Kindly help. Thank you!

Note: The operations in my function is much more complicated. I chose to oversimplify it for representation purpose.

Comment: Look into recursion! Be wary Python has a builtin recursion limit of 1000, meaning you can only call your function within itself to a max depth of 1000 times. 
https://realpython.com/python-recursion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to capture the value returned by the function and then pass it back to the function next time

```
data = [1,2,3]
for i in range(3):
    data = optimize(data)
```

Edit to add:

You don't need the "overwrite original list" operation because you are returning the new list rather than updating in-place.  Also, the parentheses around the return value are meaningless.

```
def optimize(lst):
    A = lst[0]
    B = lst[1]
    C = lst[2]
    # perform some operation, for example,
    A = A+1
    B = B+1
    C = C+1
    new_lst = [A,B,C]
    print(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```

Comment: @SayantaSeth And no need to mutate the input list.  Just do (in this case)  `def optimize(lst): return [x+1 for x in lst]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function again on the `return` statement. Also, it's necessary to have a base case where the function should stop being executed. In this case, I limited the value of `A` to 15, so it will only perform 15 function executions before reaching the base case:

```
def optimize(lst):
    A = lst[0]
    if A > 15:
        return
    B = lst[1]
    C = lst[2]
    # perform some operation, for example,
    A = A+1
    B = B+1
    C = C+1
    new_lst = [A,B,C]
    lst[:] = new_lst # this overwrites the original param with the new output
    print(new_lst)
    return optimize(new_lst)

optimize([1,2,3])
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 11]
[10, 11, 12]
[11, 12, 13]
[12, 13, 14]
[13, 14, 15]
[14, 15, 16]
[15, 16, 17]
[16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, the way you implemented the base, it is very specific to this example. This means I have to know what exact value each entry is gonna end up at. This is not really the case in my actual code. I actually want to control the stopping criterion outside the function itself. Is there a way for that?

Comment: @sayanta-seth Take a look at this tutorial: https://youtu.be/IJDJ0kBx2LM

Answer (score 0):

Calling `optimize([1,2,3])` creates a *new* `[1,2,3]` list each time it is called.  The function is mutating the passed-in list, but it is thrown away each iteration and the return value wasn't used.

If you want to mutate the input list, you need to create the list *once*:

```py
def optimize(lst):
    lst[:] = [x + 1 for x in lst]  # mutate in-place, just for illustration

data = [1,2,3]

for _ in range(3):
    optimize(data)
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
```